# can i use entity id instead of node id to load node with node_load() function

Tags: hooks

can i use entity id instead of node id to load node with node_load() function coz
i don't find any difference between entity id and node id . both node id and entity id return same result

```
$e_id = node_load($entity_id);
dpm($e_id);
$n_id = node_load($node_id);
dpm($n_id);
```

both *$e_id* and *$n_id* return exactly same result

Comment: They are totally same....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node ID *is* the entity ID for the node entity type.

As they're the same thing, the answer to your specific question can only be "yes".